# Parsing error while sending data from google spreads to Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am sending data from my google spreadsheet to Firebase. My data contains values such as "0.5 ml", "2.5 ml", etc. App Script is not being able to parse this data. Here is my code

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("****");
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var dataToImport = {};
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
   var Name = data[i][1];
   dataToImport[Name] = {
     Name: Name,
   };
 }
 var secret ="*****"
 var firebaseUrl = "******";
 var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl,secret);
 base.setData("", dataToImport);
```

}

This is the error that I am getting:

"Error: 400 - Invalid data; couldn't parse key beginning at 1:2. Key value can't be empty or contain $ # [ ] / or . (line 303, file "Code", project "FirebaseApp")"

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok...please ignore the last question. If you can address the original question please

Comment: You are able to edit the question to remove whatever is no longer relevant.

Comment: Edited accordingly

Comment: I have been able to find out the reason behind the error and found out a solution. Not sure If I can provide my own solution but still going ahead providing that. If that is against the forum rules please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind the error is the fact that Firebase does not allow some special characters in the Key of the child. As one can see my original code, I was using the name itself as my key, which contains characters like "."

I have changed my code as follows so that the key is set randomly and it is working fine:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("*****");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};
  var secret ="*****"
  var firebaseUrl = "*****";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl,secret);
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataToImport = {
      Name:data[i][1]
   };
    Logger.log(base.pushData("*****", dataToImport));
  }
}
```